# Issue regrading navbar dropdown in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, navbar, dropdown

I am facing a problem regarding a dropdown menu in my website navbar. I am using bootstrap v 3.3.6

On hover the menu name (Here it is Features), I am expecting that it should look like the button beside it (The request demo button). The right side edge becomes sharper on hover. I surfed lot on net but ultimately I did not find a needful workaround yet.

Here is my code snippet

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header"><%= image_tag("logo.png", alt: "industryPrime") %></div>
    <ul class="navigation pull-right">

        <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Features <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="paperless_purchase_section">Paperless purchase</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="efficient_stores_section">Efficient stores</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="peace_of_mind_section">Peace of mind</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      <li class="req_demo">

        <%= link_to "Request Demo", user_request_demo_page_path , :onclick => "demo_clicked()" ,:onmouseover => "start_count()" , :onmouseout => "stop_count()" %>
      </li>
        <li id="Login button section"><%= link_to 'Login', {controller: 'sessions', action: 'new'} %></li>



        <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><%= image_tag("contact_us.png") %>+91 98302-15353</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

See,the right side of the dropdown named "FEATURES" is very sharp where the left side is perfect. I want that right side should be like the left side. And one thing the blackish effect is just because of hovering.

[image: The problem snapshot is here:]

Comment: I'd expect you have `overflow: hidden` or something alike on the button container. Also - do you use any additional stylesheet?

Comment: include your css.

Comment: its none other then bootstrap css @Ron.Basco

Answer (score 0):

If you include the following css rules then the features box on the right shall receive some padding,

```
<style>
      .dropdown {
          padding-right: 10px;
        }
</style>
```

Though I have the suspicion that you are using some kind of templating language here as well which you've not mentioned.